# Which event fires when I click outside(somewhere else) after doing inline editing in Kendo grid cell

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on `Kendo` grid inline editing. When I edit a cell and click outside. Cell data is getting saved and `dirty-flag` appears.

I want to catch the event when I click outside the cell ? I am editing Numeric stepper control (number textbox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such an event raised by the grid itself. However the change event on the grid's datasource is possibly what you are looking for:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/change